# Convert stacked matrices to block matrix

Tags: r, matrix

My current data is a series of `3x3 matrices` that are stacked on top of one another. The structure looks like this (the following example is `3 matrices`, although my actual data is much larger/longer):

```
0   1   1
0   0   1
1   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   0   0
0   1   1
0   0   1
1   1   0
```

Using `R`, I would like it to look like this:

```
0   1   1                       
0   0   1                       
1   1   0                       
            0   1   1           
            1   0   1           
            1   0   0           
                        0   1   1
                        0   0   1
                        1   1   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `split` the `matrix` to a `list` of matrices by a grouping index created with `gl` and apply `bdiag` (from `Matrix`) to get block diagonal sparse matrix

```
library(Matrix)
m2 <- bdiag(lapply(split(d1, as.integer(gl(nrow(d1), 3, nrow(d1)))), as.matrix))
m2
#9 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                       
# [1,] . 1 1 . . . . . .
# [2,] . . 1 . . . . . .
# [3,] 1 1 . . . . . . .
# [4,] . . . . 1 1 . . .
# [5,] . . . 1 . 1 . . .
# [6,] . . . 1 . . . . .
# [7,] . . . . . . . 1 1
# [8,] . . . . . . . . 1
# [9,] . . . . . . 1 1 .
```

which can be converted to a regular matrix by wrapping with `as.matrix`

```
as.matrix(m2)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(9L, 3L))
d1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` together with a variable that groups each set of 3 rows.

```
split(as.data.frame(mat), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(mat) / 3)))
```

data:

```
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 9*3, replace=TRUE), ncol=3)
```